# Protocol relative URLs missing port in Rails URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, urlhelper

I'm trying to generate protocol relative URLs using Rails URL helpers. For this I set the protocol option to false. But whenever I generate a URL, the `port` part is missing.

```
dashboard (master) > rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.3)
2.0.0p247 :001 >   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
 => Object
2.0.0p247 :002 > tunnels_url(host: "0.0.0.0:3000", protocol: false)
 => "//0.0.0.0/tunnels"
```

The thing is: I'd like to generate protocol relative URL but for a custom port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be intentional.  From [url.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb), there is the code:

```
options[:protocol] = normalize_protocol(options)
options[:host]     = normalize_host(options)
options[:port]     = normalize_port(options)

result << options[:protocol]
result << rewrite_authentication(options)
result << options[:host]
result << ":#{options[:port]}" if options[:port]
```

`result` ends up being the url string you want to build.

Now, `normalize_protocol` will return `\\` if you set the `protocol: false`

`normalize_port` then looks at `options[:protocol]` specifically returning `nil` if `options[:protocol] == '//'` regardless of whether you included the port in the `host` option or specifically give the `port` option.

By doing the normalization in this order what you want seems to be impossible from the core code.

I don't know if this is an oversight or if it is deliberate.  Maybe it is considered that you cannot have a port without the protocol.  In any event it might be worth you raising an issue with Rails.

In the meantime, you could workaround it with a `gsub`.  Not brilliant but probably better than nothing.  Something like:

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > tunnels_url(host: "0.0.0.0port", protocol: false).gsub('port',':3000')
 => "//0.0.0.0:3000/tunnels"
```

Comment: Nice one!  +1 for making a pull request and not just an issue.

Comment: They just merged. Thanks, you inspired me @graeme-mclean :)